# making a list of outgoing calls one by one automatically

Tags: android, phone-call

i want to make calls to  list of phone numbers(4/5 numbers) from my phone;i made on call, after ending that call then only it has to call next number (which is automatically). what my thought is:

```
   for(int i=0;i<aray.lenght;i++)
   {
   callIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+num)); 
     startActivity(callintent);
  }
```

we know defaultly only two outgoing calls will go. i want to restrict one outgoing call has to go. and after talking/ ending ; next number will call,  this process will continue until list of numbers over.here we also have to  check the status of an outgoing call, ringing,offhookk and idle;how come we know or placed only single call by using three states. try to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this..
let nums be the list of numbers..

```
 public class CallsActivity extends Activity {

  final Context context = this;
     public String num;
     String LOG_TAG = "EMERGENCY CALL";

     public String[] pnum={"9666848344","9603939029","7404230210","9030109791"};
     ArrayList<String> b= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(pnum));
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
     num=b.get(0);
    call(num);
    // add PhoneStateListener
    PhoneCallListener phoneListener = new PhoneCallListener();
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this
        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener,
        PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);



  }
   void  call(String num1)
      {
        Intent callIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+num1));
        startActivity(callIntent);
        int indx=b.indexOf(num1);

        //Log.i(LOG_TAG, "indx"+indx);
         if (indx!=b.size())
            {
                num=b.get(indx+1);
            }  

      }

  private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;


    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

      if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
        // phone ringing
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
      }

      if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
        // active
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");

        isPhoneCalling = true;
      }

      if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
        // run when class initial and phone call ended, need detect flag
        // from CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE");

        if (isPhoneCalling) {

          Log.i(LOG_TAG, "CALL...");

      // restart app
      Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
              getBaseContext().getPackageName());
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//            startActivity(i);
         call(num);
          isPhoneCalling = false;
        }

      }
    }
  }

}
```